# How to find max&min in while loop - c

Tags: c, while-loop, double, max, minimum

I know that this is very easy question for you, but for me as beginner very hard. To get to thing. I have to create program that will take as many numbers as I want and then write max and min from them. Numbers can have decimals so that´s why double. Everything goes great as far as I trouble-shot until while cycle begins. I always get 0 on output on both min and max values. Anyone knows why?
Code:

```
 main() {
  int a = 0, b = 0, min = 1000, max = 0;
  printf("How many numbers do you want to enter\n");
  scanf("%d", & a);
  b = a;
  double n[b];
  printf("Write those numbers\n");
  for (b = 0; a > b; b++) {
    scanf("%lf", & n[b]);
  }
  b = 0;
  while (1) {
    if (n[b] < n[b + 1])
      max = n[b + 1];
    if (min > n[b])
      n[b] = min;
    b++;
    if (b == a)
      break;
  }
  printf("Minimum: %lf\nMaximum: %lf", min, max);
}
```

Comment: Why are `min` and `max` `int` and not `double`?

Comment: Are `min = 1000, max = 0` your real limits?  Maybe you should use `double min = DOUBLE_MAX, max = DOUBLE_MIN`.

Comment: ... or even `max = -DOUBLE_MAX`

Comment: If you were compiling using gcc or clang, you would have gotten a warning telling you exactly why your `printf` statements are printing zero.

Comment: Haven´t noticed that at all, Am I dumb haha... It works now, thanks! Have great day!

Comment: @FiddlingBits :  The constants in float.h are `DBL_MAX`, `DBL_MIN`.  However `DBL_MIN` is the smallest representable non-zero _positive_ value, so in fact just `0` or is signed values are intended `-DBL_MAX`.

Comment: @Clifford I've never actually used those constants. Thanks for the info.

Comment: Do not change the code after comments/answers have been given, as this renders them to be ununderstandable. Add updates. I rolled back you last change though.

Comment: Again: PLEASE do not change the code after comments/answers have been given, as this renders them to be ununderstandable. Add updates. I rolled back you last change though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Printing an `int` using a conversion specifier for `double` is not a good idea, but invokes the infamous Undefined Behaviour.

The compiler might have noticed you about this. If it didn't, then increase its warning level. For GCC use `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`.

So to fix this either make `min` and `max` be `double`

```
  int a = 0, b = 0;
  double min = 1000., max = 0.; /* Such initialisations limit your input. */
```

or leave them be `int` (decreasing accuracy), and print them as what there are, namely  `int`

```
  printf("Minimum: %d\nMaximum: %d\n", min, max);
```

Answer (score 6):

There are multiple problems:

1. You defined `min` as 1000, what if all numbers entered will be bigger than that?
2. `min` and `max` should be doubles too
3. By using `n[b + 1]` when `b == a` you're going after array bounds

The most optimal way to solve this is to calculate min/max in one loop, like this:

```
main() {
    int i, len;
    double tmp, min = NAN, max = NAN; // its better to initialize values to NAN to cover case when len is 0
    printf("How many numbers do you want to enter\n");
    scanf("%d", & len);
    for (i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        scanf("%lf", & tmp);
        if ((i == 0) || (tmp < min)) min = tmp;
        if ((i == 0) || (tmp > max)) max = tmp;
    }
    printf("Minimum: %lf\nMaximum: %lf\n", min, max);
}
```

Comment: Need to initialize `min` and `max`.

Comment: No need for the `i==0` test if min and max have been initialized.

Comment: He is initialising them: in the loop when `i == 0`

Comment: @FiddlingBits no, as I'm using (i==0) in loop

Comment: @PaulOgilvie no, as len can be 0

Comment: If `min` and `max` weren't initialized and `len = 0` what would `printf("Minimum: %lf\nMaximum: %lf\n", min, max);` print?

Comment: @FiddlingBits I've updated answer to properly cover this case

Comment: @FiddlingBits the answer edit now covers it: if there was no input what would its min and max be?

Comment: @llya Bursov yep this works just like my while loop implementation. Good job,

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm late but I think this is the best way to do this program

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int a = 0;
    int counter = 0;
    double min;
    double max;
    int counter = 1;
    printf("How many numbers do you want to enter\n");
    scanf("%d", & a);
    double val;
    printf("Write those numbers\n");
    scanf("%lf", & val);
    min = val;
    max = val;
    while(counter < a)
    {  
        scanf("%lf", & val);
        if(val < min)
        {
            min = val;
        }
        if(val > max)
        {
            max = val;
        }
        counter++;
    }
    printf("Minimum: %lf\nMaximum: %lf\n", min, max);
    return 0;
}
```

this will read in values continuously by first setting the min and max values to whatever the first value is.
I'm a c++ programmer not a c programmer but this seems like a better idea.